# When using JPA event listeners, is it possible to inject the actual event?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I understand there is the Hibernate way of creating an event listener like this:

```
public class ActivityEventListener implements PostInsertEventListener {
  
 @Override
 public void onPostInsert(PostInsertEvent event) {
  //do something
 }
}
```

and the JPA way which is like this:

```
public class ActivityEventListener {
  
 @PostPersist
 public void onPostPersist(Object entity) {
  //do something
 }
}
```

I want to go with the generic JPA solution. Is there some way in JPA to access the actual event (like the hibernate `PostInsertEvent` ) so as to access entity state information about old/current state, findDirty properties etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No that's not possible. If you need the detail information, you will have to use the Hibernate event model.